# Jquery ajax POST 500 internal server error

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I keep getting Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) indicating that the call to my controller method isnt working and I dont know why:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.dynamic').change(function(){
            if($(this).val() != '')
            {
             var select = $(this).attr("id");
             var value = $(this).val();
             var dependent = $(this).data('dependent');
             var _token = $('input[name="_token"]').val();
             $.ajax({
              url:"{{ route('tambah_aktivitas.fetch') }}",
              method:"POST",
              data:{select:select, value:value, _token:_token, dependent:dependent},
              success:function(result)
              {
               $('#'+dependent).html(result);
              }

             })
            }
           });



           $('#nik').change(function(){
            $('#username').val('');
            $('#kategori3').val('');


           });

           $('#kategori2').change(function(){
            $('#kategori3').val('');
           });

             $("select").val();



  </script>
```

My Contoroller

```
 function fetch(Request $request)
{
 $select = $request->get('select');
 $value = $request->get('value');
 $dependent = $request->get('dependent');
 $data = DB::table('users')
   ->where($select, $value)
   ->groupBy($dependent)
   ->get();
 $output = '<option value="" disabled selected >Pilih '.ucfirst($dependent).'</option>';
 foreach($data as $row)
 {
  $output .= '<option value="'.$row->$dependent.'">'.$row->$dependent.'</option>';
 }
 echo $output;
}
```

Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException
The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a link to localhost (Tip:No one can see or use that link), I'm going to assume that you're using xampp as a server.

There couldn't be multiple reasons for why your server denying you access, here are a couple of solutions:

there's a file in /Applications/xampp/etc/httpd.conf called httpd.conf, open this file and do the following:

Change:
AllowOverride AuthConfig **to** AllowOverride All

or

change the permissions of the admin folder to "755"

Comment: if i click that link, show message ' Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException
The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST. '

Comment: that's because you're running the server. The xampp server you're running only allowing you and people with access to your internet connection to see the contents. If you go to  Xampp control panel, find apache, click stop and then click the link you'll see what everyone else sees.

Comment: since the "GET" method isn't supported that mean that the server is actively denying you access, try to give you're access to the server to GET something

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are missing a select in your query.

```
 function fetch(Request $request)
{
 $select = $request->get('select');
 $value = $request->get('value');
 $dependent = $request->get('dependent');
 $data = DB::table('users')
   ->select($select)
   ->where($select, $value)
   ->groupBy($dependent)
   ->get();
 $output = '<option value="" disabled selected >Pilih '.ucfirst($dependent).'</option>';
 foreach($data as $row)
 {
  $output .= '<option value="'.$row->$dependent.'">'.$row->$dependent.'</option>';
 }
 echo $output;
}
```